# How to draw chess cage in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have such a task:

> The side of the window W and the number of cells N are entered from the keyboard so that W is a multiple of N.
> The window is painted in a checkerboard black and white square, the lower left square should be black. For example, if you enter "100 5", the following window should appear:

[image]

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# size = width, height = (1000, 1000)

width = height = int(input('Let\'s draw a chessboard =) \nSpecify the window size from 100 to 1500 pixels (it will be in 1: 1 format): \n')) 
size = (width, height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

rows = cols = int(input('Specify the desired number of squares, I will raise them to the square and build a chessboard: \n'))
square_size = width / rows


game_name = pygame.display.set_caption("The chess board")

# rgb
white_color = (255, 230, 153)
black_color = (128, 64, 0)

def draw_squares(screen):
    screen.fill(white_color)
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(row % 2, rows, 2):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, black_color, (col * square_size, row*square_size, square_size, square_size))

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.display.flip()

    draw_squares(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I found this solution, but when I enter the height of 100 and the number of squares 5, I get this picture:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use a larger width (say, 200)?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, perhaps you have issues because the window is so small

Comment: @Iguananaut then it works properly

Comment: @IainShelvingtonI also thought about it, but I just wonder why at 200 everything works well, and at 100 it breaks

Comment: As @IainShelvington wrote it's probably just a limitation on the minimum window width.

Comment: @Iguananaut Oh well, it's a pity that I can not influence it (

Comment: Maybe you can help me with another question, can I fulfill this condition otherwise not cycle in cycle, somehow easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the function that draws the chess board. The extra 20px screen width you get is because in pygame the minimum width of a window is 120 pixels. This is to accommodate for the three buttons/the minimize, close, restore/ buttons on the top right part of the window.

You can try it yourself by running this code

```
size = (100, 100)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
print(screen.get_size())
```

And the output of the program will be (120, 100).